# android - how to share app with a code inside it

Tags: android, android-sharing

I need to make an application and make my users able to send app to others with a certain code inside it and indicate which user has sent the app.
For example , I share my app to my friend and when my fried install the app , it has a static number inside it that make me able to know who is sending the app and who is the referrer .

How can I do so ? how can I put a number or something inside the app and when I share the app , I know who is asking it ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Android recommends to use "Share Intent" to share "Anything (URLs, emails, files)" with other users.

When "Something" is shared, usually a third party app is invoked (in this case it would be "Play Store App"). "Play store" App does not provide any meta data  as a parameter and it handles installation/app life-cycle at system level.

**Simple answer to your question:**

> NO - you can't get to know who has shared at the time of installation
>   through Static means

However popular solution that exist in the market are referral code input at the time of sign up !